# Media query affecting any device with portrait/landscape orientation

Tags: css, media-queries

As the title says, i'm trying to target every device in portrait mode.

My current media queries:

'mobile':

```
@media (max-width: 639px),
@media (orientation: portrait) {}
```

'desktops' etc:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 640px) {}
```

For some reason `orientation: portrait` does not affect ipad mini 2. Why?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a syntax error, try this better

```
@media (max-width: 639px), (orientation: portrait) {}
```

rather than repeating the `@media` directive

```
@media (max-width: 639px),
@media (orientation: portrait) {}
```

check on this page a more specific media queries for the ipad mini:
http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/#iPadMini

Comment: okay so now when I use 
@media only screen
  and (min-width: 640px),
  all and (orientation: landscape){} and @media(max-width: 639px),
  all and (orientation: portrait){} Ipad mini uses both of those queries at the same time in portrait mode

Comment: ipad mini portrait dimensions have a 768px width so it obeys the first part of this query "@media only screen and (min-width: 640px) , all and (orientation: landscape)" note that "," is used as an "or" logic operator you could rewrite the rule like this "@media only screen and (min-width: 640px)  and (orientation: landscape)"

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `all` to target all devices

```
@media all and (orientation:portrait) {  
    /* Portrait  */  
}  
@media all and (orientation:landscape) {  
    /* Landscape */  
}
```

Comment: You need to use all like so... `@media all and (max-width: 639px)`

Comment: It worked with the tip from Diego but I have another problem which I described under his answer

Comment: If the answer of Diego solved your initial problem you need to accept his answer. If you have an other question you need to create a new one instead of asking it in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

The Ipad Mini has an higher resolution than the one used in your media query.

Also you don't need to repeat the **@media** on each line.

```
@media(max-width: 639px),
@media (orientation: portrait) {}
```

Try:

```
@media (max-width: 639px) and (orientation: portrait){

}
```

For the ipad mini:

**IPAD MINI PORTRAIT**

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1)  { 

}
```

You can also be more specific targeting the higher pixel density of the ipad mini which is higher then the Ipad:

```
/* ipad Mini Portrait */
@media only screen and (width:768px) and (resolution: 163dpi) {

}

/* ipad Mini Landscape */
@media only screen and (width:1024px) and (resolution: 163dpi) {

}
```